# JavaScript - cloneNode gives different result

Tags: javascript, forms, clone, clonenode

I am trying to clone the form before submition in JavaScript using cloneNode. The original form has an answer for a selected value but not the cloned one. Following is the code.

```
encodeHTMLCollectionToBase64(document.forms['formen']).submit();

function encodeHTMLCollectionToBase64(form) {
encryptedForm = form.cloneNode(true)
Array.from(encryptedForm).forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.childElementCount > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i < item.childElementCount;i++) {
            item[i].value = btoa(encodeURIComponent(item[i].value));
        }
    }
    else {
        item.value = btoa(encodeURIComponent(item.value));
    }
});
encryptedForm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(encryptedForm);
return encryptedForm ;
}
```

Upon inspection I found that the encryptedForm (cloned form) has empty value for one select element but it is there in form (original form). Why is that?

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The form's selections are saved in the browser, not in the form's DOM elements, so when you clone it, the selections will not be copied over. It's possible to copy the selections over if you use JavaScript to manage the 'selected' prop on all of your form elements, or you could store the selections in a separate variable and reapply them later.

Comment: Are you saying the select values are not in the form? but it doesn't make sense. Also, upon inspection, I can see the value for the select element in the form. Could you please explain this to me? any example or something? appreciated.